# Linq query where any item from List<int> belongs to parameter string[]

Tags: c#, linq

Code:

```
string[] seperators = { "," };
string[] typesList = types.Split(seperators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string[] topicsList = topics.Split(seperators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

if (typesList.Length > 0)
    filter = filter & builder.Where(t => typesList.Contains(t.Type));
if (topicsList.Length > 0)
    filter = filter & builder.Where(t => topicsList.Any(id => t.Topics.Any(p => id == p.ToString())));
   // above doesn't work
```

My class has these properties:

```
public List<int> Topics { get; set; }
public string Type { get; set; }
```

How can I write query to make this work?

Edit:

I could be unclear as you mentioned in comments so let's focus on this code instead:

```
var list = new List<MyClass>();
list = LoadElements();
string[] parametr = { "8", "11" };

var result = list.Where(pm => pm.Topics.Any(t=> t.Equals(8) == true )).ToList();
//this above works for static '8' but I want to query through my 'parametr' list.
```

MyClass object is:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string    Data { get; set; }
    public List<int> Topics{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why does it not work? What error do you get? And what is the `filter` data type? What is `builder`?

Comment: There are MongoDB C#Driver stuff, should've make it more clear but let's say it is the type where you can use .Where statements.

Comment: What are the errors you get? Build errors? Exceptions? Please include them in your post above.

Comment: Could u look at the post again as I edited it for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = list.Where(record => parametr.Any(parm => record.Topics.Any(t => parm == t.ToString()))).ToList();
```